# How to Show and Hide a div while an input is active

Tags: jquery

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#input').focusin(function() {
                $('#input').keyup(function() {
                    $('#div').show();  
                });
            });
            $('#input').focusout(function() {
                $('#div').hide();
            });
    
        });
```

```css
#div {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>HellWorld</div>
<input id='input' type='text'>
```

In my code here, I'm trying to make my script like this

When i press on the `#input` and nothing typed, The `#div` is hidden, But when i type something in `#input` the `#div` shows up, And if i clicked out of the `#input` or `#div` the `#div` disappears, But if i returned and clicked again on the `#input` the `#div` will appear again.
How i can fix the code to do that, Also there is something weird with the `focusin&out` that if i tried to continue typing, the old result will appear again for a moment.

Comment: I don't actually know what you are trying to do. Your English is confusing me

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Chris in my code, When i click on the input and type something, the `#div` shows up, And when i click on the `document` it becomes hidden again, NOW if i clicked again on the `input` while something is still written in it again, The `#div` doesn't show up unless i wrote something or press a button again.

Comment: that means you want to show div on click or focus

Comment: @Omi yes, exactly, in both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do this, to where if you focus out, and the input value isn't empty, keep the div shown? If you're typing while focused on input, and value isn't empty, show the div, if input is empty, hide the div?

```js
var toggleDiv = function() {
  // If not empty value, show div
  if ($('#input').val() !== '') {
    $('#div').show();
  } else {
    $('#div').removeClass('clicked').hide();
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).click(function(e) {
    var targetId = $(e.target).attr('id');
    if (targetId !== 'div' && targetId !== 'input') {
      $("#div").removeClass('clicked').hide();
    }
  });

  $("#div").click(function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
  });

  $('#input').focusin(function() {
    toggleDiv();
    $('#input').keyup(function() {
      toggleDiv();
    });
  });

  $('#input').focusout(function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if ($("#div").hasClass('clicked') === false) {
        $("#div").hide();
      }
    }, 100);
  });

});
```

```css
#div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="div">HellWorld</div>
  <input id="input" type="text" />

</body>
```

Comment: I want the `#div` to be hidden if i clicked on the `document`, AND when i click again on the `#input` while what i wrote is still typed in it To make the `#div` show up again, The problem that it doesn't show up if i just clicked, It requires me to wrote or press a button.

Comment: yes, that exactly, Is `focusin` is same as `on.(focus)`?

Comment: The focusin event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, gains focus. This is distinct from the focus event, in that it supports detecting the focus event on parent elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling).

Comment: Is it possible to keep the div shown if i clicked on it?

Comment: If i clicked on the `#div` and clicked out of it, It doesn't `hide()` like before. Unless i clicked again on the `#input`

Comment: Now it is random, If `input` is `infoucs` sometimes the `#div` appears and sometimes not, And sometimes if i clicked on the `#div` it stays and sometimes not. Would wrapping both the `#input & #div` inside a div solve the problem?

Comment: Revised again, sorry bout that. Please let me know if that is better. Thx!

Comment: It worked for a while as intended, Then suddenly after doing all the actions from `infoucs` to `outfoucs` for more than 5 times it returned as before, Refreshed the Browser and doesn't work as before either unless i waited for a while and tried again. Then refreshed again and it works perfectly, But as i realized, It is affected by the `scroll` of my browser or something like that.